# How to schedule different images to change in design background

Tags: android, android-studio, background, scheduled-tasks, weather

I'm currently working on a weather project in Android Studio where I want to schedule image changes in my design background every 5 seconds, I have all the image resources in my @drawable directory. I watched a basic tutorial where they explained some things in the demo but it only helped a little and didn't quite suit me, I'm still confused because I'm getting a lot of errors but I've currently tried these few codes:

HomeActivity.java:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static int count=0;
    int[] drawablearray=new int[]{R.drawable.burj_khalifa,R.drawable.central_bank_of_nigeria,R.drawable.eiffel_tower,R.drawable.hong_kong,R.drawable.statue_of_liberty};
    Timer _t;
    
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        
        ImageView = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnMain);
            _t = new Timer();
            _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask); {
            public void run(); {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // run on ui thread
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (count < drawablearray.length) {

                                lnMain.setBackgroundDrawable(drawablearray[count]);
                                count = (count + 1) % drawablearray.length;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
    }
}
```

Any Idea on how to Organize it to suit the design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed the error by using constraintlayout in place of imageview and inmain. I also got id for the layout:

```
constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
            constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.burj_khalifa);
                _t = new Timer();
                _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                            public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // run on ui thread
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (count < drawable.length) {
    
                                    constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                                    count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }
            }, 5000, 5000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Home.this.getWindow.setBackgroundDrawableResource(drawableArray[count]);
        cout += (count + 1) % drawableArray.length; 
        h.postDelayed(this, 5000);    
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawableResource(drawablearray[count]);
        count += (count+1)%(drawablearray.length); 
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};
```

And the call is like this:

```
handler.postDelayed(r,0);
```

This will call the runnable to execute and handle.postDelayed will run the method every 5000 millsec.